# Error message when adding drift for Arima model

Tags: r

I am using the R forecast package to try to fit an ARMA (2,0,0) model. I think a drift term would help but I'm getting an error message when I try to include it.

I've tried  researching the error  message online  but  couldn't  find anything related to what I'm experiencing.

Here is my data:

```
-6.732172338
-2.868884273
-5.371585089
-6.512740463
-4.171062657
-5.738499071
-3.343947176
-1.944879508
-5.464109272
-3.189183392
-3.684700232
-2.168303451
-2.329837082
-0.761979236
-2.189025304
1.094238807
-4.812300745
0.784198777
-1.567075922
0.143963653
1.131119051
2.899746353
-0.498719993
3.121623505
```

I created a time series object with 24 annual observations. I didn't include dates because there isn't an observation for every year.

```
tsdata<-ts(read.csv("...\\Pre2001LaunchDateTraining.csv"), start = c(1,1), end = c(24,1), frequency = 1)
```

I then created a new model using the Arima () function.

```
fitdata <- Arima(tsdata,c(2,0,0),include.drift = "true")
```

After executing the above code I get this error:

```
Error in (order[2] + seasonal$order[2]) > 1 & include.drift: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types Traceback: 1. Arima(tsdata, c(2, 0, 0), include.drift = "true")
```

Comment: read.csv("...\\Pre2001LaunchDateTraining.csv") might be part of the problem...I would move that to a separate step dat <- read.csv("...\\Pre2001LaunchDateTraining.csv") and check to make sure that the values are being interpreted as numeric

Comment: @MDEWITT Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it though but I'm still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

fitdata <- Arima(tsdata,c(2,0,0),include.drift = TRUE) should work.